# SQL to find table entries by consulting foreign keys

Tags: sql

I have 4 tables as below:

1. Company: `companyid, name`
2. Employees: employeeid, name, companyid
3. Jobs: `jobid, title, companyid`
4. LinkEmpolyeeJob: `employeeid, jobid`

I want to identify invalid entries in the `LinkEmpolyeeJob` table where the employee and the job are from different company.

I want to avoid query like below because it was too slow:

```
select * 
from LinkEmpolyeeJob 
where (employeeid, jobid) not in (select a.employeeid, b.jobid 
                                  from Employees a, Jobs b 
                                  where a.companyid = b.companyid);
```

Anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `join`s:

```
select e.*, j.*
from LinkEmpolyeeJob lej join
     Employees e
     on lej.employeeid = e.employeeid join
     Jobs j
     on lej.jobid = j.jobid
where e.companyid <> j.companyid
```

Comment: Thanks. I think that is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try using LEFT JOINs like below. (Did not test the query, but should give you idea)

```
select * 
   from LinkEmpolyeeJob lej
   left join employees e on lej.employeeid = e.employeeid
   left join jobs j on e.companyid = j.companyid and lef.jobid = j.jobid
   where e.employeeid is null and j.jobid is null
```